# Timestamps into sessions pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am very new to panadas and have a DataFrame in pandas that looks like this:

```
        customer_id, timestamp   
74594,  1,           2016-05-25 15:39:41
74556,  1,           2016-05-25 15:40:33
74403,  1,           2016-05-25 15:43:26
73783,  1,           2016-05-25 15:52:40
73241,  1,           2016-05-25 16:01:01
71960,  1,           2016-05-25 16:19:35
71590,  1,           2016-05-25 16:26:05
11765,  2,           2016-05-26 18:03:18
81825,  3,           2016-05-25 13:14:55
81560,  3,           2016-05-25 13:22:15
80517,  3,           2016-05-25 13:27:36
78370,  3,           2016-05-25 13:30:58
75575,  3,           2016-05-25 15:22:00
74890,  3,           2016-05-25 15:33:56
74119,  3,           2016-05-25 15:47:57
```

How do I build session data so that as long as there is another timestamp for the same customer within 15 minutes then it is the same session, but if more than 15 minutes has passed or there's a new customer then a new session is created?

```
        customer_id, timestamp,           session_id          
74594,  1,           2016-05-25 15:39:41, A
74556,  1,           2016-05-25 15:40:33, A
74403,  1,           2016-05-25 15:43:26, A
73783,  1,           2016-05-25 15:52:40, A
73241,  1,           2016-05-25 16:01:01, A
71960,  1,           2016-05-25 16:19:35, B     <---- new session - more than 15 minutes elapsed
71590,  1,           2016-05-25 16:26:05, B
11765,  2,           2016-05-26 18:03:18, C     <---- new session - different customer
81825,  3,           2016-05-25 13:14:55, D     <---- new session - different customer
81560,  3,           2016-05-25 13:22:15, D
80517,  3,           2016-05-25 13:27:36, D
78370,  3,           2016-05-25 13:30:58, D
75575,  3,           2016-05-25 15:22:00, E     <---- new session - more than 15 minutes elapsed
74890,  3,           2016-05-25 15:33:56, E
74119,  3,           2016-05-25 15:47:57, E
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Setup

```
import pandas as pd
from string import ascii_uppercase

text = """index,customer_id,timestamp
74594,1,2016-05-25 15:39:41
74556,1,2016-05-25 15:40:33
74403,1,2016-05-25 15:43:26
73783,1,2016-05-25 15:52:40
73241,1,2016-05-25 16:01:01
71960,1,2016-05-25 16:19:35
71590,1,2016-05-25 16:26:05
11765,2,2016-05-25 18:03:18
81825,3,2016-05-25 13:14:55
81560,3,2016-05-25 13:22:15
80517,3,2016-05-25 13:27:36
78370,3,2016-05-25 13:30:58
75575,3,2016-05-25 15:22:00
74890,3,2016-05-25 15:33:56
74119,3,2016-05-25 15:47:57"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text))

df.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)

print df

    index  customer_id           timestamp
0   74594            1 2016-05-25 15:39:41
1   74556            1 2016-05-25 15:40:33
2   74403            1 2016-05-25 15:43:26
3   73783            1 2016-05-25 15:52:40
4   73241            1 2016-05-25 16:01:01
5   71960            1 2016-05-25 16:19:35
6   71590            1 2016-05-25 16:26:05
7   11765            2 2016-05-25 18:03:18
8   81825            3 2016-05-25 13:14:55
9   81560            3 2016-05-25 13:22:15
10  80517            3 2016-05-25 13:27:36
11  78370            3 2016-05-25 13:30:58
12  75575            3 2016-05-25 15:22:00
13  74890            3 2016-05-25 15:33:56
14  74119            3 2016-05-25 15:47:57
```

Build boolean series identifying when time gap is greater than 15 minutes, and another when we get a new customer_id.

```
gt_15min = df.timestamp.diff() > pd.datetools.timedelta(minutes=15)

diff_user = df.customer_id.diff() > 0
# or
diff_user = df.customer_id != df.customer_id.shift()

session_id = (diff_user | gt_15min).cumsum()

df['session_id'] = session_id.map(pd.Series(list(ascii_uppercase)))

print df

    index  customer_id           timestamp session_id
0   74594            1 2016-05-25 15:39:41          A
1   74556            1 2016-05-25 15:40:33          A
2   74403            1 2016-05-25 15:43:26          A
3   73783            1 2016-05-25 15:52:40          A
4   73241            1 2016-05-25 16:01:01          A
5   71960            1 2016-05-25 16:19:35          B
6   71590            1 2016-05-25 16:26:05          B
7   11765            2 2016-05-25 18:03:18          C
8   81825            3 2016-05-25 13:14:55          D
9   81560            3 2016-05-25 13:22:15          D
10  80517            3 2016-05-25 13:27:36          D
11  78370            3 2016-05-25 13:30:58          D
12  75575            3 2016-05-25 15:22:00          E
13  74890            3 2016-05-25 15:33:56          E
14  74119            3 2016-05-25 15:47:57          E
```

Comment: Awesome! Is there something similar to diff_user = df.customer_id.diff() > 0
for strings as well?

Comment: `diff_ = df['some_string'].ne(df['some_string'].shift().bfill()).astype(int)`